# Obstetrician needs help! How to exactly synchronize system time between iPhone and Windows 10 Laptop

Tags: iphone, synchronization

We are trying to develop a low-cost ultrasound device that can be used by inexperienced operators for health care in developing countries. We have created a low-profile optical tracking system that connects to the ultrasound probe. It outputs positional data from both the binocular camera and an on-board 9-axis IMU. The ultrasound pictures are collected on an iPhone at a frame rate of 60 per second and are time stamped to the millisecond based on the iPhone system time. The optical tracker collects positional data onto a Windows 10 laptop. We need to exactly synchronize the system time of the 2 devices (iPhone, laptop) at least to 1/10 sec and preferably to the millisecond.

Is there a way to access the precise system time on the iPhone and synchronize this with the laptop?

Full disclosure: I am an obstetrician and not an engineer. But I’m not satisfied with the story I’m getting from the developers about this. It must be possible.

We've tried pointing the laptop to the same internet clock as the iPhone, but the sync is not good enough. Maybe because of wifi latency?

Comment: Why don't you collect all the data using the laptop, timestamp it, then display it on the phone? Using 2 distinct systems to do similar things with the same data and expecting them to be in sync is going to cause more headaches than anything. Even NASA has problems with this type of timing differences.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really a second-opinion service for what your employees tell you. Unfortunately, time synchronization is not as simple as you seem to think it is.

Comment: Thanks for these comments. I hope David M's comment doesn't chill responses to my query. I'm not being a policeman, I'm just trying to solve a problem. We don't have a way to collect the ultrasound data on the laptop as proposed by @computercarguy - its a closed system and only works with the IOS device. I guess what I'm asking is whether it is possible to access the precise system time on an iPhone via the lightning connector. If we could pull this off the phone onto the computer just once at the beginning of the session, this would be good enough to synchronize. Thanks.